# boost variant comparator

Tags: c++, comparator, variant

I need to compare two variables of type `boost::variant` and I want to compare the values inside the variant for equality.

What would be the best way to implement this?

My variant looks like this:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, float, double, long, bool, std::string, boost::posix_time::ptime> variant;
```

Comment: Are you sure you *really* need this variant?

Comment: Yes I do need this variant...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [variant docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/variant/reference.html#variant.concepts.bounded-type):

> EqualityComparable: variant is itself EqualityComparable if and only if every one of its bounded types meets the requirements of the concept.

So `variant` already implements equality if all the types are comparable. So in your case you should be able to just use the operator `==`.

In general, you can implement a binary visitor by creating a unary visitor that encloses a reference to one of the arguments and applying the visitor to the second argument.

Comment: Though this is not a real problem, with boost 1.45 and VC100 "==" works but "!=" works not an gives a compiler error (" no operator found ...").